# How can I clean my data better? Asking for a friend

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I'm just starting out, so I try to build things that work first and then think of how can I improve the code.

I've been working with CoinGecko's API to dump data like prices. The first issue I got is that query returns a list of lists. Each entry contains a UNIX timestamp and a value.

[image: API GET request returns a dictionary that contains 3 lists of lists]

First, I used pandas to put this data into a DataFrame.

```
data = cg.get_coin_market_chart_by_id('bitcoin', 'USD', 'max')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

It returned a DataFrame with each cell containing a list with a UNIX timestamp and a value.

[image: Dictionary to DataFrame]

Obviously, I wasn't happy with each cell containing a UNIX timestamp. So, I made 3 DataFrames out of each Series. I also formatted UNIX timestamps in new indexes to datetime in each.

```
price = df['prices'].apply(pd.Series)
price.columns = ['date', 'price']
price = price.set_index(['date'])
price.index = pd.to_datetime(price.index, unit = 'ms')
price.columns = ['price']
market_cap = pd.DataFrame(df.market_caps.values.tolist(), index = df.index)
market_cap = market_cap.set_index(0)
market_cap.index = pd.to_datetime(market_cap.index, unit = 'ms')
market_cap.index.names = ['date']
market_cap.columns = ['market_cap']
volume = pd.DataFrame(df.total_volumes.values.tolist(), index = df.index)
volume = volume.set_index(0)
volume.index = pd.to_datetime(volume.index, unit = 'ms')
volume.index.names = ['date']
volume.columns = ['volume']
```

Finally, I concatenated all 3.

```
dfs = [price, market_cap, volume]
conc = pd.concat(dfs, axis = 1, sort = False)
```

[image: Final result]

I'm not a CS guy or anything, but I want to learn how to manipulate data well. I let you, wizards of StackOverflow, use whatever unpleasant words when describing my code as long as it helps me to improve. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not use links to images in the question. Try to have everything in your question.

Comment: @csymvoul I'm happy to do so. Could you suggest a good link to follow and learn about how to do this? I was using the default "upload image button" and here I can see a user suggests the same: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Apologies for my previous comment. You should upload an image as shown here: [![enter image description here][1]][1] ..... [1]: https://url

Comment: @csymvoul I believe they are necessary for the context. I just shared the same link above and I used the method described there to attach images.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just updated my comment. Just copy and paste what I wrote and place the URL of your image

Comment: Just placed the images in the question. If you want you can approve my changes

Comment: Please always provide your examples **as text**. And make sure to provide a [mcve]. We should be able to copy and paste and re-produce your stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, `pd.DataFrame` accepts a dictionary like this:

```
{column0:{index0:value0, index1: value1, ...}, ...}
```

So, just transform your input data by making a dict out of the inner lists:

```
In [22]: import pandas as pd

In [23]: data ={
    ...:     'prices': [[1367107200000, 135.3], [1367193600000, 141.96]],
    ...:     'market_caps': [[1367107200000, 1500517590], [1367193600000, 1575032004.0]],
    ...:     'total_volumes': [[1367107200000, 0], [1367193600000, 0.0]]
    ...: }
    ...:

In [24]: pd.DataFrame({k:dict(v) for k,v in data.items()})
Out[24]:
               prices   market_caps  total_volumes
1367107200000  135.30  1.500518e+09            0.0
1367193600000  141.96  1.575032e+09            0.0
```

And to get an actual datetime index, use:

```
In [26]: df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.index,unit='ms'))
Out[26]:
            prices   market_caps  total_volumes
2013-04-28  135.30  1.500518e+09            0.0
2013-04-29  141.96  1.575032e+09            0.0
```

or even in one, fell, swoop:

```
In [28]: from datetime import datetime
    ...: pd.DataFrame({
    ...:     k:{datetime.fromtimestamp(x/1000): y for x,y in v}
    ...:     for k,v in data.items()
    ...: })
Out[28]:
                     prices   market_caps  total_volumes
2013-04-27 17:00:00  135.30  1.500518e+09            0.0
2013-04-28 17:00:00  141.96  1.575032e+09            0.0
```

Although that's getting a bit ugly, IMO.

Comment: Man, this looks beautiful, heaps better than my wall of code. I only have 2 questions: 1. When you made dictionaries out of the inner lists, keys were UNIX timestamps, right? 2. When you applied to_datetime first, your output had no hours:seconds:ms, and the second time it was different. How it’s reflected in the code? Sorry if the questions are stupid.